# What does "single British English accent" mean in this particular context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

I found this sentence on the Cambridge website. It was provided as a description of a book. Please explain the phrase "single British accent."

> You will gain confidence in all areas of English pronunciation, including individual sounds, word accentuation, connected speech and intonation, and can practice with simple "listen and repeat" exercises **modeled with a single British English accent.**

Comment: Please link the source

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means all the examples will use the same accent. And that accent will be one specific British accent. It doesn't say which British accent, but probably the accent used in the South of England (around London) by high-status individuals.

Comment: And the reason it mentions the singularity is to suggest that it’s a benefit to learners. You won’t end up pronouncing some vowels like a Londoner, others like a Yorkshireman, and still others like a Glaswegian; such mishmashes can strike native speakers as odd.

Comment: Heh. Well you made the edit, so I'm happy to keep my word. Answer deleted. Now if I can interest you in editing out that conjunction at the beginning of the sentence, or perhaps changing it to an "Also"... :-)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149958/discussion-on-answer-by-james-k-what-does-single-british-english-accent-mean-i); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.